# Use Storybook docs with Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, storybook

It seems like the only proper way to write custom docs content for the Storybook Docs addon is through MDX, implying that it was meant primarily for React. The addon page explicitly lists Svelte as a compatible framework, but no deployment instructions seem to be around.

Suppose I have a simple component:
`button.svelte`:

```html
<script>
  export let text;
</script>

<button on:click>{text}</button>
```

And the respective story, `button.stories.js`:

```js
import Button from './button.svelte';

export default {
  title: 'Button',
};

export const button = () => ({
  Component: Button,
  props: {
    text: 'press me!',
  },
});
```

How would I go about adding arbitrary markdown documentation with Storybook Docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure your Storybook Docs addon is set up to parse MDX by installing [all required dependencies](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/master/addons/docs#installation).

```sh
yarn add -D react react-is babel-loader
```

Then you can write your MDX docs in a separate file with an `.mdx` extension, [embedding your stories](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/addons/docs/docs/mdx.md#embedding-stories) instead of writing them out explicitly.

Create a `./docs.mdx` file in the same directory as `button.stories.js` with your desired documentation:

```
import { Story, Preview } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks';

# Button

One can write __proper Markdown__ here, as well as embed stories:

<!-- the IDs can be retrieved from the URL when opening a story -->
<Preview>
  <Story id="button--button" />
  <Story id="button--other" />
</Preview>

<!-- or an individual story -->
<Story id="button--flat" />
```

Then, modify your `button.stories.js` as follows:

```js
import Button from './button.svelte';
import docs from './docs.mdx';  // add this import

export default {
  title: 'Button',
  parameters: {  // and this parameters section
    docs: {
      page: docs,
    },
  },
};

export const button = () => ({
  Component: Button,
  props: {
    text: 'press me!',
  },
});

// Another story just for demonstration
export const other = () => ({
  Component: Button,
  props: {
    text: 'me too!',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To Add to @illright answer i got it working with just using an mdx file. After following the setup update the regex in storybook config to match on mdx files as well as js/ts files if using `/\.stories\.([jt]s|mdx)$`

Then you can define the stories using jsx style syntax within the mdx file like this.

```
import { Story, Preview } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks';
import {text, withKnobs} from "@storybook/addon-knobs";
import Avatar from "@common/avatar/Avatar.svelte";

# Button

One can write __proper Markdown__ here, as well as embed stories:

<Meta title="Components/Avatar" decorators={[withKnobs]} />

<Preview>
    <Story name="Normal">
        {{
             Component: Avatar,
             props: {
                 imageUrl: text('Image Url', '/default-profile-image.png'),
                 size: text('Size', '2.35rem'),
             },
         }}
    </Story>    
</Preview>
```

Using svelte style syntax is something that could be coming in the future, hopefully you could define it something like

```
<Preview>
    <Story name="Normal">
        <Avatar imageUrl="/default-profile-image.png" size="2.35rem"/>
    </Story>    
</Preview>
```